# Terminating all methods in a cocoa app and re-initing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to terminate all currently called methods and then simply re-init my current object.
So when the user clicks on say the Start button, I call a bunch of methods...start doing stuff. Then when the user clicks on Cancel, i need to simply stop all running tasks/methods and re-init.

I don't want the app itself to terminate. So cannot use [NSApp terminate:nil]. I just need all current functions to stop and then i can call [self init];
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to set some flag and disable your user interface until all methods are completed. For example, `self.cancelled = YES`.

Next, each of your methods should be adjusted to return if that flag is set:

```
- (void)doSomething
{
    if (self.cancelled) return;
    // ...
    for (/* ... */) {
        // ...
        if (self.cancelled) return;
        // ...
    }
    // etc...

}
```

Then, you need a mechanism to track all your methods. Most likely, you will use `NSOperationQueue` or `dispatch_queue_t`. Take a look into documentation to find out how to get a notification when the queue becomes empty.

Finally, reset the `self.cancelled` flag and unblock your user interface.

Comment: But if i do that in every method and the code gets past the check, and then the user hits cancel, then how do I handle it ? I can think of ways to handle this that would not be very clean. Was hoping there is some other easy way where everything gets re-init, other than the app window closing

Comment: I may misunderstand, but it looks like you want to do something undoable :) Unfortunately, there is no way to ‘break’ a method execution. Your code must have a way to return when some flag is set or some condition is met, if you do not want to relaunch the app.

Comment: Overall, having a button Cancel always visible and enabled is not very good user experience. You do not need to add cancellation logic into every single method of your app. Usually the Cancel button interrupts only one operation, no matter how complicated it is. So only that operation should support ‘cancelling’.

Comment: It would be a good idea to adopt NSOperationQueue for another reason: Its design presents a fairly obvious, certainly straightforward, way to create cancellable operations. You break the work up into indivisible chunks, each modeled by an NSOperation. When the user cancels, you cancel all the operations that are already in the queue. Any chunks that are already running will finish (as they should), and the rest will not be started.